# Two Apps using the same user account

Tags: java, android

I have two apps which use the same user account. Like Amazon with "Amazon Shopping" and "Prime Video".

I'd like the user to have the possibility, to automatically log in, in the second app - if he is logged in, in the first app.

Does anybody know how to make this in a secure way?

Comment: Use IPC to communicate between two application.

Comment: @Godfather And which one I should use?

Comment: I would suggest `ContentProvider` with a signature-level permission. It will make your data (such as auth tokens) accessible only to the apps signed with the same signing key.